# Partially override Page level filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am having challenges getting this measure to work as expected. I have to adjust costs in the current month by calculating the cost in the past months closed and then averaging them.

```
Adjusted costs = 
VAR closedmonth = ClosedMth[ClosedMth Value] -- What-if parameter
VAR selectedyear = MAX(Financials[Year])
VAR selectedmonth = MAX(Financials[Month])
VAR currentmonth = MONTH(NOW())
VAR currentyear = YEAR(NOW())
VAR previousyear = YEAR(NOW())-1
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        CALCULATE(
            SUM(Financials[Amount]), 
            FILTER(Financials,
                Financials[Account] IN {"50900", "50910"})),
        FILTER(
            ALL(Financials[Month],Financials[Year]),
            Financials[Month]<=closedmonth && Financials[Year]=previousyear))
```

The measure works properly if I add a slicer for the year and one for the month and have the current month manually selected.
However, I would like to remove those slicer and have that dynamically set so I wrote a calculated column for the current year/month and added it as a page filter.

```
Current = 
VAR presentMonth = MONTH(NOW())
VAR presentYear = YEAR(NOW())
RETURN
    IF(Financials[Month]=presentMonth && 
       Financials[Year]=presentYear,
        "Current", "Past")
```

Unfortunately, once I add this Filter to the Page level filters, the row context overpowers the filter context from the measure. I also tried using a Relative Slicer but couldn't solve the problem. In my case, editing interactions wouldn't work either. I would still want to use a page level filter but somehow have the measure display the correct result.

Can someone help me rewrite the measure in order to achieve my goal of only displaying the results for that month by calculating past months costs? How can I get around this problem?